# How can I use Leaflet with esri-leaflet and ArcGIS Online services

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-online, esri-leaflet

I've used public ArcGIS Online services plenty of times in ESRI JS web apps and I imagine that using them as layers in Leaflet is pretty much the same. The one problem I can see is how would one access a private service? In the ESRI JS api provides an Identity Manager to facilitate OAuth and cookie handling. Leaflet provides no such facilities.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an existing example up on GitHub which [shows how to use simple OAuth authentication](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/), and an [open issue for supporting private services](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/issues/139). The project is currently a development preview, but feel free to chime in on GitHub with your thoughts or, if you have running code already, pull requests.